# Counting numbers greater and less than input using 4 variables

Tags: algorithm, loops, counting

I got a request for help with exercise (dedicated for primary school students) to prepare a program that counts numbers greater and less than input with limitation to using 4 int variables.

> Write a program that reads one integer *N*. It will then read *N* integers and print out how many of these numbers were greater than *N* and how many were less than *N*.

I used kotlin  for my attempts just for more readable example, but language doesn't matter.

```kotlin
val sc = Scanner(System.`in`)

println("N: ")
var A = sc.nextInt()
var B = 0
var C = 0
var D = 0

while (D < A){
    println("--> ")
    B = sc.nextInt()
    if (B > A) {
        C++
    }
    D++
}

println(C)

while (C > 0){
    C--
    A--
}

println(A)
```

Finally code must be describable by pseudocode like this.

```
1. load into A
2. if D < A jump to next otherwise jump to 8
3. Load to B
4. if B > A jump to next otherwise jump to 6
5. Increase C by 1
6. increase D by 1
7. jump to 2
8. write out box C
9. move to a new line
10. if C > 0 jump to next otherwise jump to 13
11. decrease C by 1
12. decrease A by 1
13. write out box A
```

I did some attempts to solve problem but I have no idea how to handle numbers that are equal that should not be counted.
I started to have some doubts that it is possible with restriction that not allowing more variables.

Comment: @nocomment between the ages of 9 and 14, I wonder if this is not a matter of some mistake on the part of the task creator

Comment: I guess they should know division and modulo by then, the trick I used. Or maybe there's something else I'm overlooking.

Comment: To my surprise this turned out to be an interesting question!

Comment: (Kept my impulse to prompt to *ask an explicit answerable programming question* in check.)

Comment: For example, when considering to use a 4-byte size variable as four 1-byte areas. If such a method is permissible, what is the meaning of the limitation to the number of variables?

Comment: If the problem were "[...] how many of these numbers were greater than N and how many were less than **or equal to** N." you could use the fact that `gt_N = N - lte_N`. Then you would need a variable for N, the current element, the iterator, and one of the counts.

Comment: Solutions don't belong into questions but into answers. Please remove it and post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd use **five** variables. So I combine the two counts in one variable.

```py
N = int(input())
count = 0
i = 0
while i < N:
    i += 1
    number = int(input())
    if number > N:
        count += N+1
    if number < N:
        count += 1
print(count // (N+1), 'were greater than', N)
print(count % (N+1), 'were less than', N)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3f_gp2Cpk5pVoZOYVlJZoaGpyJeeX5pUABQ24MsFkeUZmTqpCpoKNgp8VlwIQZCpo2yoYgpl5pblJqUXoJoAVpcEk7WD6QABiOFC_n7YhmjobrOoMuQqKQIZDBPT1FTSAOjV1FNTLU4tSFdKLUhNLgHpLMhLz1HUU_DRRVKuiKs5JLS5GqIT4HxoMC5YbcxlymXAZQrgA)

Without division/modulo:

```py
N = int(input())
count = 0
i = 0
while i < N:
    i += 1
    number = int(input())
    if number > N:
        count += N+1
    if number < N:
        count += 1
i = 0
while count > N:
    count -= N+1
    i += 1
print(i, 'were greater than', N)
print(count, 'were less than', N)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuha3GMX8FGwVMvNKNDLzCkpLNDQ1uZLzS_NKgIIGXJlgsjwjMydVIVPBRsHPiksBCDIVtG0VDMHMvNLcpNQidBPAitJgknYwfSAAMRyo30_bEE2dDVZ1hiiugAjDTYRwdZFMg2gpKAK7R0dBvTy1KFUhvSg1sQRoQ0lGYp66joKfJlQBWDtMUU5qcTFCBSR4oKG0YLkxlyGXCZchhAsA)

Comment: Very nice! However, I don't know of any elementary school students that could come up with this, except for one 7-year-old girl.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Well, the OP said they're between the ages of 9 and 14. So if even a 7-year-old can come up with it...

Comment: Great solution, really clever :) but in this context wont help

Comment: @radzmiv Hmm? Why not?

Comment: @nocomment, a Whac-a-Mole rule change?

Comment: @nocomment mayby i negate to fast, i need to check that mayby will by possible to implement modulo and floor division by that simply assembly-like syntax

Comment: @radzmiv I can easily do it without them (added that to the answer now), but that's getting ridiculous. Both pseudo-code and assembly should have those. Looks like Cary is right about this being a never-ending whac-a-rule game.

Comment: Possible way to encode/pack the information into one variable will be depends on size of the variable and max of N. So, more definition needed to accept/reject the way likes this post, I think.

Comment: @nocomment So finally it is solution that solved that issue, thanks for help.

Task required in addition implementation of modulo and div.

Answer (score 0):

It seems straightforward. Am I missing something?

Variables are `N`, `cp`, `cm` and `e`.

```
N = <read value>.to_i
cp = 0
cm = 0
N.times do
  e = <read value>.to_i
  if e > N
    cp = cp + 1
  else if e < N
    cm = cm + 1
  end
end

puts "#{cp} values greater than #{n}"
puts "#{cm} values lest than #{n}"
```

`to_i` is a method that converts a string to an integer.

Comment: you dont consider that "N.times" is syntax sugar that hides the counter

Comment: radzmiv, that depends on the language. In Ruby, for example, no counter is needed: `count = 0; 3.times { count = count + 1 }; puts count #=>  "3"`. I should point out that in programming competitions I've had with elementary school students I trounced them all, except for one 7-year-old girl.

Comment: @CarySwoveland i updated post for better problem explanation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nocomment solution, resulting pseudocode looks like this.
It was necessary to implement divide and modulo without predefined function.

```
1. load into A
2. if D < A jump to next otherwise jump to 10
3. Load to B
4. if B > A jump to next otherwise jump to 6
5. increase C by 1
6. If B < A jump to next otherwise jump to 8
7. increase C by A
8 increase D by 1
9. jump to 2
#modulo counting
10. Set B to C
11. if B >= A jump to next otherwise jump to 14
12. decrease B by A
13. jump to 11
14. write box B
#div counting
15. move to a new line
16. set B to 0
17. if C >= A jump to next otherwise jump to 21
18. decrease C by A
19. increase B by 1
20. jump to 17
21. write box B
```